# Get node author's real name in views or convert username

Tags: 7, views, theming

I currently have a content view that displays a list of nodes for a blog. I would like to display the node authors real name (John Smith) at the top, but currently I am only able to display their username (john_smith) by creating a relationship to Content: Author and then adding User: Name.

How can I grab some fields from the node authors user profile?

The fields I need are $field_first_name, $field_last_name, $field_position.

FYI: I realize that there are modules that might be able to fix this problem such as [Real Name](https://drupal.org/project/realname), but I am hoping to do this without it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use any special modules and you have simply added fields to the user acount (on /admin/config/people/accounts/fields then you should be able to add those fields in the Views UI. Just like you do it with all other fields, except that you use the author relationship that you have already created.

Comment: Ha! I must have needed to save it. I swear it wasn't there. It's there now! Thanks.